# Two way one to one associations in Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In my application I'm having two way 1:1 relationships between models. When trying to set an association between them i get ...

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

... and the trace repeats

```
OrderedSet.forEach
Map.forEach
DS.Model.Ember.Object.extend.toJSON
DS.Model.Ember.Object.extend.addBelongsToToJSON
DS.Model.Ember.Object.extend.toJSON
Map.forEach
OrderedSet.forEach
```

Relevant parts of the code:

```
App.Employee = DS.Model.extend( {
    // ... 
    recruitment:DS.belongsTo( 'App.Recruitment', { embedded: true } )
} );

App.Recruitment = DS.Model.extend( {
    // ...
    employee:DS.belongsTo( 'App.Employee', { embedded: true } ),
} );

// ...

recruitment.set('employee', employee);
employee.set('recruitment', recruitment);
App.store.commit(); // <= boom
```

Is this something that Ember Data should support or am I approaching this all wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ember-Data does not support one-to-one associations at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. I supppose this is functionality that will be available in the stable release?

Comment: I found [this github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/120) where the issue is being discussed. It seems like I just have to implement some workaround myself for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed, and is now a straight-forward process of making the models belong to each other:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  profile: DS.belongsTo('profile')
});

App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

The above is an example from http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/