# Ember Data, Relationships, output of attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two entities with fixtures data: `User` and `Role`. When I load a `User`, it contains one `Role`. I would like to show the name of the role. Here is relevant code:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    role: DS.belongsTo('App.Role'),
});

App.Role = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});
App.User.FIXTURES = [{
id:1,
name:'user',
role:1
}];
App.Role.FIXTURES = [{
id:1,
name:'reader',
}]

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
  return App.User.find();
 }
});

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
           {{#each controller}}
              {{name}} {{role.name}}
           {{/each}}
 </script>
```

the name of role is not displayed but if I change it to `{{role.id}}` the id of role is displayed

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856590/two-way-one-to-one-associations-in-ember-data

Answer (score 0):

i think you may need to add

`users: DS.hasMany('App.User')`

to the definition of your `Role` model.

Comment: no, it doesn't help. the problem is the initialisation of role in user over role's id

Comment: have you tried `role_id: 1` instead of `role: 1` in `App.User.FIXTURES`?

Comment: then i'm at a loss. sorry for wasting your time.